# Private const defined on class level and then used on an attribute, why this compile?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, private

Have a look at the following code:

```
public class Person
{
    private const string MyConst = "SomeValue";

    [MyAttribute(MyConst)]
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

`MyConst` is defined as `private` and in my opinion it should not be accessible for MyAttribute. However this code compiles well.

Anyone knows the reason?

Comment: Why *exactly* do you think it shouldn't be accessible? Consult the language specification and see if you can find the rule you *think* should be broken...

Comment: I don't see why you think it shouldn't compile.

Comment: @Ash I think because `MyAttribute` is a separate class from `Person`, and `MyAttribute` should not be able to access private members in another class. However, in this case, `MyConst` is passed to the constructor of `MyAttribute` and this is perfectly legal.

Comment: @JonSkeet I understand that the constant is visible in the class body. But I thought because MyAttribute is defined over a Property as Meta Data (and it's not really a part of the class) it won't be able to access the private constant. But obviously I was wrong ;-)

Comment: @gsharp: Well it's part of the class body - it's within the text of the class declaration. More interesting would be whether you could use that value in an attribute applied to the class itself - where you really *could* argue that it's not in the *body* of the class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Private members are only accessible within the same class body as where they're declared. I guess it's accessible because you're declaring and using it in the same class.